# How do i solve this square root to solve for $y$ and get rid of $x$ at the same time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratic-forms

This is what I have and I don't know how to solve for $y$. Because $x$ is a variable it would be great if it would cancel out.

$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{2.25^2Ax^2 + 2.25 \cdot2Bx}}{\sqrt{Ax^2 + 2Bx}} = \sqrt{\frac{2.25^2Ax^2 + 2.25 \cdot2Bx}{Ax^2 + 2Bx}}
$$

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this correctly?

Comment: Yes I have. The problem is that above I cannot seem to factor out the 2.25...

Answer (score 0):

It is already solved for $y$.  You can plug in any value for $x$ you want (given $A,B$) and evaluate it.  Why do you expect to be able to get rid of $x$?

Comment: I am supposed to get a $y$ but I don't know $x$. I hoped it is possible to get rid of it.

Comment: At least from here you won't do better.  Do you have information on $A,B?$  Are they related to $x$ somehow?  Or both zero?

Comment: I am familiar with the equations in that question, but don't see how you get from there to here.  It looks like you are trying a specific case-what particle and what momentum?  What are $x,y$?

Comment: The problem is quite large in fact. I was trying to keep it simple. The full problem is in fact posted in Physics stackexchange here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72253/problem-similar-to-davison-germer-eksperiment-but-with-more-angles-and-the-mir